# PointStacker - Random locations at different zoom level

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wps

I'm applying PointStacker transformation on one of my layers using Geoserver 2.5.2 and OpenLayers 2.

I know, that I have 7 datapoints located on the exact same location. 
However, when I change the zoom level the stacked point is moving around randomly.
I would've thought that the stacked point's location is calculated by the mean of the vector points being stacked. In other words, if they are located at the same location, it shouldn't move around changing zoom levels.

What am i doing wrong?

zoom level 7:
[image: zoom level 7]

zoom level 8:
[image]

zoom level 9:
[image]

zoom level 10:
[image]

zoom level 11:
[image]

Comment: It is an OpenLayers 2 problem with marker display. Every marker I tried to use jumped randomly in different zoom levels. I don't know if because of this, but the marker function got deprecated in OpenLayers 3.

Comment: I'm using geoserver as WMS source, meaning no markers are placed on the map via javascript/OpenLayers. All markers get rendered on geoserver side. OpenLayers is just requesting the map tiles from geoserver and Google maps. In this aspect I do believe something is fishy on geoserver side.

Comment: Just checked with OpenLayers3, the same issue exist.

Comment: I looked up GeoServer's manual for the Point Stacker function. It didn't say anything about clustered point placement. Maybe it is an issue coming from coordinate rounding in different scales, but it's just an assumption. One thing sure, this isn't a native problem in GeoServer, since OL2 is doing this, too with markers.

Comment: If you set the `isFixed` property of your vector layer to `true`, the problem still persists?

Comment: Sorry for getting back this late. Yes it still exists. Actually I've found out that PointStacker transformation will always be applied over a grid of the current map extent. Meaning: even if you have a single point, this transformation will add an offset to it in order to place the point near the grid cell's center. This is something they've missed out from the official documentation. :(

Comment: This is the same issue as described here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155520/geosever-pointstacker-renders-incorrect-position  You can find the answer also there: "...I added that in my SLD: <ogc:Function name="parameter"> <ogc:Literal>preserveLocation</ogc:Literal> <ogc:Literal>Superimposed</ogc:Literal> </ogc:Function>. Where possible parameter are: Single, Superimposed, and Never. Now the rendered WMS cluster map is -not perfect- but much better."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about how PointStacker calculates the cluster point's location is incorrect. It doesn't use centre of mass in the way you'd expect.

The bounds of the images request are broken up into a grid and clusters are created for each cell of that grid. So if you have what looks to you like a natural cluster, e.g. 3 points close to each other, they will only be clustered together if all 3 are in the same grid cell. If they fall into 3 grid cells they will be assigned to 3 separate clusters.

As you zoom in the points do not land in the same grid cell as in the previous image and therefore the cluster is given a new location relative to the image's width and height.

This is not the most intuitive behaviour but it does make for a much simpler clustering algorithm. You can see the code here: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/PointStackerProcess.java

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is caused by the cellSize parameter.

If you set this parameter to 1 (the locations you want to aggregate are exactly the same then the marker should be displayed at that location.

If you increase the cellSize the marker will be placed somewhat randomly inside a buffer defined by the cellSize in pixel.

```
<ogc:Function name="parameter">
 <ogc:Literal>cellSize</ogc:Literal>
 <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
```